# Gitlab docker in docker deployment unable to access private registry

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I set up a private gitlab registry on a docker host. On the same host I'm trying to build test images and push them to said registry.
For some reason, this is not working. Here is my gitlab ci config:

stages:
      - build_testing
      - analytics
      - testing
      - build_deployment

```
variables:
  MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'true'
  MYSQL_USER: 'dev'
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'dev'
  MYSQL_DATABASE: 'debitor_management_test'

# image: 10.11.12.41/laravel:v1

# services:
# - name: mariadb:10.1
#   alias: mysql

image: docker:stable
services:
- name: docker:dind
  command: ["--insecure-registry=10.11.12.41:443"]


build_testing:
  stage: build_testing

  script:
  - docker build -t 10.11.12.41/debitor_management_testing .
  - ping -c 5 10.11.12.41
  - docker push 10.11.12.41/debitor_management_testing
```

The ping command is working, but the `docker push` fails with

```
$ docker push 10.11.12.41/debitor_management_testing
The push refers to repository [10.11.12.41/debitor_management_testing]
Get https://10.11.12.41/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting   for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the CI runner cannot communicate with `10.11.12.41`.

Every GitLab repository has an associated [Container Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/container_registry.html) for storing Docker images. You might better off using that rather than running a custom registry for storing images. GitLab CI provides [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) to your CI jobs such as `CI_REGISTRY`, `CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE`, `CI_REGISTRY_USER`, and `CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD` to help you access the registry associated with your repository.

If you use the built-in registry, you can write your `build_testing` job like the following.

```
build_testing:
  stage: build_testing

  script:
    - docker login --username $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY      
    - docker image build -tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .
    - docker image push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
```